# How to get Prometheus to fire alert after first occurrence is resolved?

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I'm new to Prometheus, and to learn how to use it I've set up some dummy code that mimics rising and falling tides. Some high tides are higher than others, and I want to send out an alert during these "Extreme high tide" events.

However, only one alert fires in the alertmanager/Prometheus instance resulting in only one notification sent to Slack. This alert fires the first time the conditions in `rules.yml` are met, is resolved after the time limit, and then never fires again.

Here are my config files, starting with Prometheus:

```
global:
  # Global scrape period
  scrape_interval: 15s
  
  # How frequently to evaluate rules
  evaluation_interval: 250ms

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'
    
rule_files:
  - rules.yml
  
# Alerting specifies settings related to the Alertmanager
alerting:
  alertmanagers:
    - static_configs:
      - targets:
        # Alertmanager's default port is 9093
        - localhost:9093
    
remote_write:
  - url: https://prometheus-us-central1.grafana.net/api/prom/push
    basic_auth:
      username: <User Name>
      password: <Grafana API key>

scrape_configs:

  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name:       'Tides'
    scrape_interval: 500ms
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:8000']
        labels:
          group: 'Experimental'
```

Then `alertmanager.yml`:

```
global:
  resolve_timeout: 2m
  slack_api_url: "<slack_webhook API key>"
route:
  receiver: 'slack-notifications'

receivers:
- name: 'slack-notifications'
  slack_configs:
  - channel: '#<your slack channel>'
    send_resolved: true
```

And finally my `rules.yml`:

```
groups:
- name: TideAlerts
  rules:
  - alert: ExtremeHighTide
    # Condition for alerting
    expr: current_sea_level > 4
    for: 0s
    
    # Annotation - additional informational labels to store more information
    annotations:
      title: 'Extreme High Tide'
      description: 'Alert: Current sea level has greatly exceeded mean high tide'

    # Labels - additional labels to be attached to the alert
    labels:
      severity: 'critical'
```

I've tried to make the scrape and rules evaluations to be on a short enough interval that nothing should be missed, but no avail.

**EDIT:** Here is the simple python code I wrote to test out Prometheus and alertmanager:

```
from prometheus_client import start_http_server, Summary, Gauge, Histogram
import random
import time
import math

# Create Prometheus metrics
REQUEST_TIME = Summary('request_processing_seconds', 'Time spent processing request')
LEVEL = Gauge('current_sea_level', 'Height of Tide at Time (Seconds)')
STATUS = Gauge('current_tide_direction', 'Status of tide (Incoming Outgoing High Low)')

buckets = (0, 0.05, 0.1, .15, .2, .25, .3, .35, .4, .45, .5, .55, math.inf)
REQUEST_HIST = Histogram('latency_histogram', 'Latency Histogram', buckets=buckets)


@REQUEST_TIME.time()
def measure_sea_level(t):
    """A toy function that 'measures sea level' with some latency."""

    t = t/10

    time.sleep(max(0, random.normalvariate(0.3, 0.1)))
    level = 4 * math.asin(math.sin(t / 2)) * math.cos(t - 2)
    df = dfdt(t)

    # {rising: 1, falling: -1, high: 2, low: -2}
    if abs(df) > 0.25:
        status = math.copysign(1, df)
    elif dfdt(t - 1) > 0:
        status = 2
    else:
        status = -2

    return level, status


def dfdt(t):
    return 2 * (math.cos(t / 2) * math.cos(t - 2)) / \
           (2 * math.sqrt(1 - math.sin(t / 2) ** 2)) - \
           4 * math.asin(math.sin(t / 2)) * math.sin(t - 2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # Start up the server to expose the metrics.
    start_http_server(8000)

    while True:
        with REQUEST_HIST.time():
            tide_level, tide_status = measure_sea_level(time.time())
            LEVEL.set(tide_level)
            STATUS.set(tide_status)

            if tide_level > 4 and tide_status == 2:
                print('Extreme High Tide')
```

Comment: @rcarba that User name and password were fake, but I don't want any more jokes popping up in my slack channel :)

Comment: Can you post which metrics your tides app provides? You are speaking of you get only one alert, that sounds like you expect more. Maybe distinguish between "alert" (which is the concept an prometheus and the alert manager) ande the notification in slack. E.g. you have one alert and you get two notifications (rising and resolved)

Comment: @JensBaitinger I added the code that exposes the metrics to Prometheus at the bottom of the question. I'll make the distinction that alerts are only firing a single time in Prometheus with a corresponding single alert and resolution pair in Slack.

Comment: Make sure you are scraping the Prometheus itself too, then check graphs of `ALERTS{alert_name="YOU_ALERT"}` for pending/firing state of the alert. 
With your current expression of `current_sea_level > 4` you should get notification on each `repeat_interval` of Alertmanager, if it persists firing, and get resolved notification after `2m` of non-firing. What else do you expect to happen here?